# Is it possible to search a storefield in lucene

Tags: search, lucene

As the title, I have indexed emails, I stored email subject in lucene store field.

Now I want to perform a search by giving a subject, I found it nearly impossible to search by subject.

Comment: what is your question can you post some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't search on that field.  When you index a document with a [`StoredField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html), that field will not be put into the search index in any way.  It will only be stored with the document such that you can retrieve it from a document (usually, one found by searching other fields).

For an email subject, you should probably use [`TextField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html), which can also be stored, if you wish, like:

```
Field subjectField = new TextField("subject", myEmailSubject, Field.Store.YES);
```